# Can't change active class of link after click in navbar bootstrap 4 with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, sass, bootstrap-4

I need to change active class of link after click in navbar of bootstrap 4 with jquery. But it's not working. Code that I have in jquery perfectly works with other links, but not working with navbar. What's the problem?

Navbar code:

```
<header class="d-flex main-header">
    <div class="container header-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse main-navigation fixed-top">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center content-nav-wrapper col-10 offset-1">
                <h1 class="mr-auto"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/site_logo.png" alt="logo"></a></h1>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right offcanvas-toggle menu-button align-self-center" type="button"
                        data-toggle="offcanvas"
                        data-target="#js-bootstrap-offcanvas" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-offcanvas navbar-offcanvas-touch navbar-offcanvas-right menu"
                     id="js-bootstrap-offcanvas">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Jquery for changing active class after click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar .navbar-nav li a").click(function () {
        $(".navbar .navbar-nav li a").removeClass("active-nav-link");
        $(this).addClass("active-nav-link");
    });
});
```

Also I have jquery for smooth scroll to sections after click and changing color of link and background of it when user scrolls page to one of the sections. Maybe problem in it:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var $sections = $('section');
    $sections.each(function(i,el){
        var top  = $(el).offset().top-100;
        var bottom = top +$(el).height();
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var id = $(el).attr('id');
        if( scroll > top && scroll < bottom){
            $('a.active-section-link').removeClass('active-section-link');
            $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').addClass('active-section-link');

        }
    })
});

$("nav").on("click","a", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 800);
});
```

I'm using Sass, my code for navbar and links:

```
.main-header {

  .header-container {
    width: inherit;
  }

  .menu {
    overflow: hidden;

    .nav-link {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 1.2rem;

        &:hover {
          color: #2ecc71;
        }
    }
  }

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
.menu {

      .active-section-link {
        color: #2ecc71;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .active-nav-link {
        color: #2ecc71;
      }
    }
```

}

Comment: It seems to be working. What part is not working for you?

Comment: After click on the link in navbar I want it to have other color of it, but color doesn't changes to color which I need, it changes to default color of bootstrap which is gray.

Comment: I added some my jquery code, maybe problem in it

Comment: The JS seems ok, show us the CSS code.

Comment: Added my Sass for navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed class of ul and added some styles.scss code.

First of all in the `ul` list I changed class `navbar-nav` to `nav`. Need to do this, because gray color was attached to class `navbar-nav`.

And in the styles added this:

```
     .nav { 
          flex-direction: column; //for mobile version
        }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {

      .main-header {

        .menu {

          .nav {
            flex-direction: row;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

After all of that I achieved what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is an issue with the scss, as you define the `.active-nav-link` style under the `@media (min-width: 768px)` query. This makes your style effective only on viewports wider than 768px. Try to put this definition outside of the query like so:

```
.main-header {
  .header-container {
    width: inherit;
  }

  .menu {
    overflow: hidden;

    .nav-link {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 1.2rem;

      /* new place */
      &.active-nav-link {
        color: #2ecc71;
      }

      &:hover {
        color: #2ecc71;
      }
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .menu {
      .active-section-link {
        color: #2ecc71;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      /*.active-nav-link {
        color: #2ecc71;
      }*/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need it to work only on viewports wider than 768px. But your solution didn't hepled. Link still have gray color after click. I can't understand why active class can't override bootstrap gray color after click.

Comment: Please check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dferenc/ymgksnm3/). This seems to be working with your original code, except that I've change the media query to `@media (min-width: 300px)` in order to showcase the behaviour in Fiddler's smaller iframe as well.

Comment: I have found interesting thing, code working and active class changes after click on the link, but after click on the link it becomes gray, BUT when I clicking on the any place on the page link become of the color which written in active class instead of gray.

Comment: and this gray color that appears because of bootstrap class .nav-link

Comment: Than it must be because of the `:focus` pseudo-selector. In this case one way to overcome this is to use the `!important` flag: `color: #2ecc71 !important;`.

Comment: it didn't helped, but when i using `:focus {color: #2ecc71}` on `.nav-link` gray color disappears, but when page is scrolling and active class changes on scroll, #2ecc71 color of clicked link stays on the link, can I make this color to move with the .active-section-link or change it to white? Here how it looks - https://ibb.co/fzCyzb (link to screenshot) First green link is clicked link, third link is link to which page was scrolled